# Next.js - Framer motion : Attempted import error: 'useState' is not exported from 'react' (imported as 'useState')

Tags: reactjs, node.js, next.js, node-modules, framer-motion

I am working on a next.js project where I want to use framer-motion. I have just started the project, and am facing an issue in installing and using framer-motion. I am trying to create a simple motion.div component and use it in another component.

```
ERROR I get in the terminal while running "npm run dev" : 

./node_modules/framer-motion/dist/es/animation/hooks/use-animated-state.mjs
Attempted import error: 'useState' is not exported from 'react' (imported as 'useState').
```

I am using the below libraries/packages:

[image]

[image]

I have tried downgrading the framer-motion version, but it's not working. It would be great if someone could help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding "use client" to my component needed the framer-motion api

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes, I have already added but still the same error.